# Using Type Inference with fluent interfaces

Tags: c#, vb.net, type-inference, fluent-interface

I have a class /interface hierarchy. On the interface side I have

```
IQuery
  ISelect      (inherits IQuery)
  IUpdate      (inherits IQuery)
  etc
```

On the class side I have

```
QueryBase       (implements IQuery)
  SelectQuery   (implements ISelect)
  UpdateQuery   (implements IUpdate)
  etc
```

Obviously, for example, both Update and Select classes share a WHERE clause but only a Select has GROUP BY functionality so ideally if an Update Query is being creating, the fluent interface will not give access to GROUP BY functionality but would do if a SelectQuery was being created.

eg in fluent interface terms

```
  var/Dim select = New SelectQuery()        <- returns ISelect explicit
                          .AddColumn(....)  <- returns ISelect explicit
                          .AddWhere(....)   <- returns ISelect inferred
                          .AddGroupBy(....) <- returns ISelect explicit

  var/Dim update = New UpdateQuery()        <- returns IUpdate explicit
                          .AddSet(....)     <- returns IUpdate explicit
                          .AddWhere(....)   <- returns IUpdate inferred
```

I am unsure how to implement the AddWhere function.

Previously I had declared the AddWhere function in the IQuery interface as

```
Function AddWhere(ByVal condition As ICriterion) As IQuery

IQuery AddWhere(ICriterion condition)
```

but because it was returning an IQuery, I was losing the benefits of the type inference and so as soon as the fluent interface had cast to the IQuery, if it was a Select query being created, I would no longer have access to, eg, the AddGroupBy method.

So I have tried to implement it as an Extension Method with generics

```
<Extension>
Public Function AddWhere(Of T As IQuery)(Byval this as T, Byval condition as Condition) as T
    this.SetWhere(condition)
    Return Me
End Function

public T AddWhere<T>(T @this, Condition condition) where T : IQuery
{
    @this.SetWhere(condition);
    return this;
}
```

with a Friend (internal) method, SetWhere, on QueryBase to permit me to update the WHERE clause. However because the generic is constrained to IQuery, it won't find the SetWhere. However, if I constrain as QueryBase, then, obviously, the compiler throws wobblies saying that the ISelect can't find an AddWhere method.

I'm thinking that I haven't quite got the inheritence chain or interface implementations quite right for what I'm trying to achieve.

(I hope that is clear!!)

I'd be grateful if someone could suggest either where I am going wrong in terms of the extension method implementation, or how I should better structure my class/interface hierarchy.

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723648/how-to-inherit-method-but-with-different-return-type might be useful reading since it discusses a simplified form of what you are trying. It largely says that its not possible though a few workarounds are there including making your base classes Generic. I think this last part (dtb's answer) will probably do what you want if you are happy with the restructuring of your code.

Comment: Chris I played with this a bit. That q talks to concrete classes only and I'm wondering if my scenario is complicated by an interface hierarchy as well. I tried genericising the QueryBase to QueryBase(of T as IQuery) but that would then mean, AFAICS, that my, eg, "SelectQuery factory" would need to return either a SelectQuery or a QueryBase(of ISelect) rather than an ISelect. Similarly the fluent methods would need to return concretes. I was returning pure interfaces because of ISP/ease of mocking. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know. I know that the question was slightly different and would need some adapting if it would work but I haven't done this before and don't have the time to play with it myself. It might be that those questions won't help you solve things perfectly, I was just hoping. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public Interface IQuery
    Function AddWhere() As IQuery
End Interface

Public Interface IUpdate : Inherits IQuery
    Overloads Function AddWhere() As IUpdate
End Interface

Public Interface ISelect : Inherits IQuery
    Overloads Function AddWhere() As ISelect
    Function AddGroupBy() As ISelect
End Interface

Public Class QueryBase : Implements IQuery
    Public Function AddWhere() As IQuery Implements IQuery.AddWhere
        ''...
        Return Me
    End Function
End Class

Public Class UpdateQuery : Inherits QueryBase : Implements IUpdate
    Public Shadows Function AddWhere() As IUpdate Implements IUpdate.AddWhere
        MyBase.AddWhere()
        Return Me
    End Function
End Class

Public Class SelectQuery : Inherits QueryBase : Implements ISelect
    Public Shadows Function AddWhere() As ISelect Implements ISelect.AddWhere
        MyBase.AddWhere()
        Return Me
    End Function
    Public Function AddGroupBy() As ISelect Implements ISelect.AddGroupBy
        ''...
        Return Me
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: You're welcome - I didn't realize how old the question was until I'd answered it. Glad it's still useful.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use another interface in your hierarchy, something like:

```
interface IQuery

interface IConditional : IQuery

interface ISelect : IConditional

interface IUpdate : IConditional
```

The `IConditional` interface could then have the `AddWhere` method, either directly in the interface definition or as an extension method constrained on the `IConditional` type.

Comment: What would the AddWhere return though? It would still have to return an Iquery or an IConditional in that situation wouldn't it?

Comment: Reading through your question again, is there any reason why an `AddWhere` has to come before a `AddGroupBy` for Select? Also what do you ultimately want to return? To me it sounds like your var will be of type `IQuery` which then has some kind of execute method, correct?

Comment: I suspect as much as anything else the answer is there any reason why it shouldn't come before? The point of fluent stuff is I believe that the methods return the same object they were running on so if you run a method on an ISelect you should get an ISelect back, not an IQuery. There are ways if you were to constrain AddWhere to the last thing but it wouldn't be truly fluent (for example because you would then have access to a different set of methods on it). I should also note that I am not the original poster so my views may not be their views. :)

Comment: IMHO I don't see why a fluent interface has to return the exact same object throughout the chain. My understanding of a fluent interface is that methods/functions are named and designed in such a way that you can read through it in (almost) plain English. Take the [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) LINQ method for example - that gets passed an `IEnumerable<T>` but returns an `IOrderedEnumerable<T>`. As long as you can return something useable for the next operation I don't see how that is not fluent

Comment: Peter/Chris ... thx for your thoughts. Peter, as you point out above, in my original implementation the AddGroupBy needed to be added before the AddWhere so works as you suggest ... but that I felt broke the SQL metaphor I was going for. Hence I was trying to improve the api.